Movie about a man who pretends to be Jewish at the end of WW2 and befriends a Jewish family
I saw a trailer for it several years ago, definitely after 2010.  Now I can't remember the name, nor can I find it on the internet by using keywords.  It may have been an indy film and it may have been in another language.
The plot is that a man is about to be arrested by the allies at the end of WW2.  At the point he says that he is Jewish and that he is with a Jewish family that happens to be walking by.  The family goes along with it.  The daughter in the family and him develop some feelings.  All this is from the trailer.  
P.S.   It's not the one where a German becomes an Israeli general.
P.P.S. If I were to guess, the release year was 2014, but not 100% sure.

Welcome to Movies&TV. Do you remember release year, language, country or other plot details, any at all? Add them so that it can help identify this movie. Also see How to ask Identify-this-X questions.

@AJ Thanks.  I added as much detail as I could remember.  I hope my memory is not faulty.

Good. Though it seems a movie I'm not familiar with. Hope someone here might know the movie. Meanwhile, if you remember more details, feel free to add them.

Sounds like Lore (2012) 

Left to fend for themselves after their SS officer father and mother,
  a staunch Nazi believer, are interred by the victorious Allies at the
  end of World War II, five German children undertake a harrowing
  journey that exposes them to the reality and consequences of their
  parents' actions. Led by the eldest sibling, 14-year old Lore , they
  set out on a harrowing journey across a devastated country to reach
  their grandmother in the north. After meeting the charismatic Thomas,
  a mysterious young refugee, Lore soon finds her world shattered by
  feelings of both hatred and desire as she must learn to trust the one
  person she has always been taught to hate in order to survive.
.......While walking, Lore again runs into the same man. She keeps on
  walking and he follows them. A truck with American soldiers drives up
  and stops. When asked for identification, the young man says his name
  is "Thomas" and shows the soldiers his Jewish identification papers
  and says he is Lore's brother. We see he has a serial number from a
  concentration camp tattooed on the inside of his forearm. The
  Americans give them a lift.

Lore (2012)  Trailer




Wow, that is it.  I got most of the fact wrong, and you still guessed it!!!
